# How to convert a gif into a shadow?

Tags: css, imagemagick, gif

I have [an elegant 3D animation of a molecule Codeine_3d_transparent.gif](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Codeine_3d_transparent.gif).

[image]

I wish to produce its`shadow : Codeine_3d_transparent-shadow.gif`, which using some html and css I will put bellow the colorful animation.

**How can I do it quickly ?**

As of now I do this but it's not a shadow XD :

[image]

Comment: If you -1 the question please give an hint (comment) so I could learn and improve.

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by `shadow`? - like border, drop shadow, outer glow to alpha 0... It is not very clear (at least to me) - i mean by default that won't be possible, but if you can tell what you have in mind, there could be a way to word around and create such effect.
Btw if you want color chaning border with smooth transition, why not use the said transition?

Comment: I assume you mean a shadow under the object as though the shadow is on a flat surface. The only way I can think of is to deconstruct the gif add the shadow to every frame and the reconstruct it again. But I have no idea how you could make an accurate shadow shape of each position.

Comment: @AdamK. : same shape, dark, below.

Comment: @Hugolpz oh now i get it... Give me a sec, i might got an idea.

Comment: Imagine there is a light source near you and a basked ball flies between you and a wall, there is a circular shadow on the wall... Something like that.

Comment: @Hugolpz i'd be nice to upvote your post and bring some attention to it. It's very interesting idea, that have never occured to me - still it's nice to find some stuff to keep the "gears" turning ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, this will probably hurt some devices performance AF (pardon me) - especially so many filters on GIF. Filters should be GPU accelerated though.

Also note, that filters aren't 100% supported across all browsers.

```css
.animationHere,.animationHere:after{
      position:relative;
      width:200px;
      height:200px;
      display:inline-block;
      background:url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3e/Codeine_3d_transparent.gif);
      background-size:100% 100%;
    }
.animationHere:after{
      position:absolute;
      top:3px;
      left:3px;
      content:"";
      z-index:-1;
      filter: brightness(0) blur(1px);
      opacity: .5;
    }
.animationHere.next:after{
      position:absolute;
      top:30px;
      left:0;
      filter: none;
    }
```

```html
<div class="animationHere"></div>
<div class="animationHere next"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's that ! :D
Which part turns the image in grey ?

Comment: @Hugolpz it's the brightness (0) - that actually turns it black. Opacity .7 (or .2) turns it transparent - so it's not grey per se, but transparent black

Comment: @Hugoplz to reproduce something like in your next image: https://jsfiddle.net/a130bhd7/5/